# How to extract values from list of dictionary that match the keys in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of keys:
`l_keys = ['a', 'c', 'd']`

And I have a list of dictionary:
`l_dict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a':4, 'd':5}]`

The result I want to get is:
`[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'd': 5}]`

.

I can achieve this result in the following way

`[{k: d[key] for k in l_keys if k in l_dict} for d in l_dict]`

.

Explain:
I actually go through every object in l_dict and then I go through every key in l_keys and check if that key is in the current object and if so I retrieve it and its value

My question is if there is a better, professional and faster way in terms of time complexity to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your list comprehension should be: `[{k: d[k] for k in l_keys if k in d} for d in l_dict]`

If you know that `len(l_keys)` will usually be smaller than the `dict`s in `l_dict`, your way is the most efficient. Otherwise, it would be better to check whether each key in the `dict` is in <s>`l_keys`: `[{k: d[k] for k in d if k in l_keys} for d in l_dict]`</s> `l_set = set(l_keys)`: `[{k: d[k] for k in d if k in l_set} for d in l_dict]`

This page might be helpful when it comes to time complexity: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#dict

Comment: Making `l_keys` a `set` would be better

Comment: I do not agree with your answer so it depends on ```len(l_keys)``` because even if the list is larger it's still worth sticking to the solution I suggested.
because searching in dict is done in O(1) while searching in list (k in l_keys) is done in O(n).
And therefore the second solution you suggested is performed in O(n^3)

Comment: I forgot to mention, first convert `l_keys` to `l_set = set(l_keys)`.